# How to get file name encrypt file upload codeigniter in looping for

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

```
for ($img=0;$img<=5;$img++)
{
    if (!empty($_FILES['picture_add_'.$img]))
    {
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('picture_add_'.$img))
        {
            $uploaded = $this->upload->data();
            $data_picture_add = array(
                                    'filename'  => $uploaded['file_name'],
                                    'id'        => $last_id
                                    );
            $this->db->insert('db_picture_individual', $data_picture_add);
        }
    }
}
```

if I input 2 file picture or more, I just get one filename encrypted.

How to get all filename encrypted ?

this is the view :

```
<input name="picture_add_1" class="form-control" style="padding-top: 0;" type="file">
<input name="picture_add_2" class="form-control" style="padding-top: 0;" type="file">
<input name="picture_add_3" class="form-control" style="padding-top: 0;" type="file">
<input name="picture_add_4" class="form-control" style="padding-top: 0;" type="file">
<input name="picture_add_5" class="form-control" style="padding-top: 0;" type="file">
```

Comment: Show the HTML for the form you are using please

Comment: RiggsFolly: Thanks for your suggestion, I have inserted the view code above.

Comment: I think what you really need to do is read this part [of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: And then this part [of the codeigniter manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use config inside your loop statement.

```
        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($_FILES); $i++) {
           $config = array();
           $config['upload_path'] = './media/project_files';
           $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
           $config['max_size'] = '51200';
           $config['max_width'] = '5000';
           $config['max_height'] = '5000';
           $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
           $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

            $ups = $this->upload->do_upload("upload_file$i");
            $imgName[$i] = $this->upload->data();
        }
```

Comment: Kazi Nayem: I have set $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; in my controller code, but one data that stored to DB, and file upload working, if I input 3 file picture, picture will upload to directory 3 file, but in DB just 1 data that stored. how to store all data input to DB?

Comment: Kazi Nayem : Actually there is nothing wrong in the code that I made above, I realized that the first image data I store in a different table. thats way the data less one. but thanks for your time :)